# python base64 decoding encoded image to PIL and saving it as png

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, base64, python-imaging-library

Hello I want to decode a base64 string that is an image that I have encoded using JavaScript the way I encoded it was I turned it into a bitmap then encoded the bitmap now I am trying to decode it in python and this is what I did I have a hash.txt file that has base64 data in it I copy the file place it in the variable definition and it works then I try f.read() and it fails this is the code

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

def decode_base64_to_bitmap_and_save(base64_string, output_file_path):
    try:
        # Decode the base64 string to bytes
        decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_string)

        # Create a BytesIO stream from the decoded bytes
        byte_stream = BytesIO(decoded_bytes)

        # Open the image using Pillow (PIL)
        decoded_bitmap = Image.open(byte_stream)

        # Save the decoded bitmap as a PNG file
        decoded_bitmap.save(output_file_path, "PNG")

        return True  # Successful save
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return False  # Saving failed

# Example usage:
file_path = "hash.txt"
with open(file_path, "r") as file:

    base64_string = file.read()

output_file_path = "output.png"

if decode_base64_to_bitmap_and_save(base64_string, output_file_path):
    print(f"Image saved as {output_file_path}")
else:
    print("Failed to decode and save the image.")
```

I tried f.read i tried the + "==" to the f.read to add padding i tried to remove the \n with "" so i remove all the \n from the base64

this is the encoding file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;

Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
String encodedString = bitMapToBase64(imageBitmap);
AfterPictureBase64(encodedString);
```

and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emojWFKclcFC5FvsmNYCp_n7e5ZZDfXf/view?usp=drive_link) is the base64 file

Comment: Try `print(base64_string[:20])` and report back what it gives you.

Comment: If it failed, what exception was printed?

Comment: @MarkSetchell this is what it gave me iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE

Comment: @ekhumoro if decode_base64_to_bitmap_and_save(base64_string, output_file_path):
       
  File "f:\decoding.py", line 11, in decode_base64_to_bitmap_and_save
    decoded_bitmap = Image.open(byte_stream)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3280, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)

and if i copy and paste the base64 string without f.open it works normally

Comment: @ian Try `open(file_path, "rb")`. The `b64decode` function accepts either bytes or an ascii string.

Comment: The first two bytes you show indicate it is a valid PNG image without any extraneous headers/coding on the front, so there is something going wrong later in the file, so @ekhumoro suggestion looks reasonable. Or maybe your base64 encoder added unexpected/unacceptable line-breaks.

Comment: hello @ekhumoro thank you for answering i tried it it tells me "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding" but again if I copy the file directly it does work but when I try to open it ,it doesn't work .I really don't know what is happening

Comment: Either share the base64 file using some other service (such as Google Drive or Dropbox) or share the **minimal**, **complete** code necessary to generate one using the method you used.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks you for replying I did it you can see the link

Comment: Please allow access.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry I did it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong but you have stray characters in your file `hash.txt`.

You can delete them like this:

```
# Load base64-encoded image from disk
with open(hash.txt, "r") as file:
   data = file.read()

# Remove extraneous rubbish
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(data.replace('\\n', ''))

# Wrap in BytesIO and open as PIL Image
im = Image.open(BytesIO(decoded_bytes))

im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: it works i would've voted but i cant thank you (i dont have 15 rep)